# I want to print an answer and it should still look good

Tags: feature-request

I want to make a nice printout of an awesome answer with lots of pictures and pretty equations. If I select the answer and use the print feature in the browser then the formatting is lost (paragraphs are too wide) and the equations don't show properly.

I want to turn this (select answer text and print)

> [image]

into this (properly rendered answer)

> [image]

I propose each answer (or question) has a link to a printable page.

**Edit 1**

Use [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/339325/392) for example.

Comment: http://www.stackprinter.com/ is better than just the print feature on *my* browser, but as a feature request this probably belongs on the mother meta.

Comment: Most other sites don't have MathJAX to deal with while rendering/printing

Comment: But there are quite a handful that do, so the problem is far from unique to physics.

Comment: I tried stackprinter and it does not separate out the answers (to focus on one answer, or keep them on new pages). So the answer I am interested in is split between two pages. Also the UI to get to the right SE site and find the ID is rather clunky. Why couldn't they just accept a full URL as produced by the [share] button. I digress.

Comment: ja72 is right: The stackprinter.com page only prints entire threads, not individual answers.

Comment: I get decent (not perfect) results on a sample post by running the Markdown source through [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) to convert it to LaTeX, adding the necessary boilerplate, and compiling to PDF. That could probably be generalized.

Answer (score 2):

If you like the way that the printout of the entire page looks, but you want only one answer to print, try this:

In Firefox on Windows:

1. Open the menu item Tools > Web Developer > Style Editor.  (The style editor is part of the "inspector" and there are a couple of ways to get to it.)
2. This is the [CSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) for the page. Add, somewhere outside of any other block (I went to the end), two lines like these:

   ```
   .question, .answer { display:none; }
   #answer-80449 { display: block; }
   ```

   When you add the first line, all the questions and answers (which live within HTML containers like `<div class="question">` etc.) will disappear; when you add the second, any code contained in `<div id="answer-XXX">` will reappear. The phone number is the post ID, which you can extract from the "share" link (or confirm by viewing the source).
3. Your printed view should match what's on the screen.

Now my Firefox seems to be having [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4609007), but since the answer in your example fits on a single page I haven't attempted to fix it.

I'm sure this feature is available in other browsers. The tricky part is figuring out where to add the CSS; the code that you add should be the same.

I see in your comments that you're probably not thrilled about this sort of "clunky interface," but this is the sort of thing that's probably pretty easy for someone to turn into a browser extension.

Comment: I edited the question pointing to an answer which should fall over a page break.

Comment: @ja72 Darn -- I'm not sure how to fix that issue.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a nice suggestion for mother Meta. In the meantime, I want to point out that if you right-click anywhere on the page, and select `Print...`, then you can (at least on my browser) choose PDF as the destination. The result usually looks nice:
[image]

I'm not sure if this is what you had in mind.

An alternative is to click on the `edit` button of the answer you want to print, copy the source code, paste into a Latex document, and compile it yourself.

Comment: For me it prints the entire page which includes: question, all answers, links and other extraneous information. I think that the ability to print a single answer (with possibility of including the question for context) would be great.

Comment: @ja72 I agree. For now, I think your best option is to print as a pdf, and then crop the important parts. Not ideal, but it kinda works.

Comment: It sucks when the answer I want to focus on is split across pages. Besides most people don't have good pdf edit tools.

Comment: @ja72 hmm to avoid the splitting, you could perhaps sort by "activity" instead of "votes"? that does fix it?

Comment: It's unfortunate that there's no "Current view" in print options (at least on Chrome).  Generally that would be my go-to solution for that; but apparently that feature is mostly in PDF viewers, not all printing.