# Printing questions on PSE

Tags: support

Since  the layout has changed I have some problem printing questions and answers: the text is pressed to the left in a very narrow space causing a huge waste of space, paper and toner.

The text has never filled the whole page because of the items featured onthe right hand of the page, but now the waste is excessive.

### Is there a trick to get the text of the answers on a full page?

Trying to print this question: it takes a whole page, I get:

..
..
..

Since the layout has

changed I have some

Comment: Related mother meta posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22877/209806 , https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/212885/209806

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to print out a Q&A to a piece of paper?

Comment: Previously, [printing single answers](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9933/44126) rather than entire threads.

Comment: @rob, I use chrome, and even if I save it as PDF I get same formatting

Answer (score 1):

You can visit http://stackprinter.com, which is a printer-friendly static mirror of the site network.

There are also various (legal) mirrors of the site network on the whole net, including the 3-monthly archive.org [data dump](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) (which is being made public by the SE itself). Using it to print a single question is obviously overkill, but if you want to do it with *many* questions, selected and ordered by your own criteria...

The printer-friendliness of the page could be also increased easily by a little  usercss (chrome addon [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-css/okpjlejfhacmgjkmknjhadmkdbcldfcb)).

Comment: I don't seem to be able to find "Physics" on stackprinter.com. Is it just me?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform There is a selection menu just on the frontpage, and the PSE is in the list (the alphabetical ordering is not their strong point, unfortunately). [This](http://www.stackprinter.com/export?question=10836&service=physics.meta.stackexchange) is the URL of our current question.

Comment: Ah, yes, I found it. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong, but anyway. Thanks!